# Interpretation of a time dependent and a complex-valued energy

Tags: complex-systems

Concerning relation 61 of [Time fractional Schrödinger equation: Fox's H-functions and the effective potential](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4773100),

1. For time dependent energies, when time tends to infinity, the energy tends to zero. Could you elaborate on this?
2. In fractional calculus, how one interpret a complex-valued energy?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.